# dosage of clavamox for a large cat

Tags: cats, medicines

I have a 16.5 pound cat who is neutered and is out in the daytime.  He is in at night but seems to get into scrapes with neighborhood cats who come into "his territory" in the daytime when he is out.  My vet usually prescribes clavamox liquid and I asked her for some tablets to keep on hand in case he got hurt after hours or on weekends so I could get him started on antibiotics asap.  He is FIV positive which is why he can't be inside all the time with my other two cats and also why I want to get him on antibiotics quickly after getting bitten.  She gave me 125mg tablets which is equal to more than the 1.5 ml liquid he usually takes.  Can I break these tablets and give him only 3/4 each time then discard the 1/4 leftover.  Of course it is the weekend now and I can't call her. I've heard you shouldn't divide tablets that are not scored but I am afraid of overdosing with the whole 125mg tablet.

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange Janice, is there an emergency vet or an emergency clinic you can call? Most of us on here are not vets so we might not be able to help. Emeregency clinics usually have a phone open on the weekends too, just try.

Comment: Thanks SerenaT.  My current vet is new to me and she didn't give an emergency #.  I think he will be okay until Monday but I like to try and stay on top of things where his health is concerned of course,  I went ahead and gave him 3/4 of the tablet.

Comment: Good to hear that you and your cat are ok. If this worked for you, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Wait, so you're putting your FIV positive cat out to infect OTHER CATS instead of keeping him inside? That's incredibly irresponsible; please speak to your vet about the risk you're inflicting on your neighbors and community cats.

Comment: Where do you think he got the FIV?  Perhaps when he was a fulltime outside cat.  I do  the best I can in not so perfect situations.  All cats should be inside all the time.  My vet knows the situation.

Comment: Talk to your vet about this antibiotic usage. You should be giving full courses of antibiotics, not just a pill or two. Occasional usage is a recipe for drug-resistant bacteria strains.

Comment: Also, in general, medication dosages apply to a range of weights. Making up numbers here, if 75mg applies to a 10-15 lb. cat, the 10 lb. cat is getting 50% more per pound of body weight than the 15 lb cat (7.5mg vs. 5mg). So the entire pill is not going to be a toxic overdose if 3/4 is the equivalent of the liquid. Finally, if you are cutting the pills, why throw away the remaining 1/4? You could give the 3 1/4 leftovers as every 4th dose.